# How to take a user input and apply in 'for’ loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, input, average

I'm a beginner to Python.
I'm trying to take an input from the user and use it in a for loop. But it doesn't work. I also tried to use range function but it also did't work!
Is there any other way to do it?

This is the Code:

```
numbers = int(input('10 numbers: '))
sum_of_all_number = 0
result = ''
for each_number in numbers:
    sum_of_all_number += each_number
    result = sum_of_all_number / 10
print(f'The average is {result}')
```

output:

```
10 numbers: 1234567890
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Documents\Python\school project duplii.py", line 4, in <module>
    for each_number in numbers:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you please state the desired outcome. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the goal is to sum up 0 to 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code without changing the logic behind do this:

```
numbers = input('10 numbers: ')
sum_of_all_number = 0
result = ''
for each_number in numbers:
    sum_of_all_number += int(each_number)
    result = sum_of_all_number / 10
print(f'The average is {result}')
```

Output

```
10 numbers: 1234567890
The average is 4.5
```

Of course the result/average must not be inside the loop, so do simply:

```
numbers = input('10 numbers: ')
sum_of_all_number = 0
for each_number in numbers:
    sum_of_all_number += int(each_number)
result = sum_of_all_number / 10
print(f'The average is {result}')
```

Comment: Than you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
numbers = int(input('10 numbers: '))
sum_of_all_number = 0
result = 0
count = 0
for each_number in range(numbers):
    sum_of_all_number += each_number
    count += 1
result = sum_of_all_number / count
print(f'The average is {result}')
```

Comment: The top line says `10 numbers` so there would need to be an array (list) of 10 numbers and not just one number which is what input would give.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do. But I think this is what you want to accomplish.

```
sum_of_all_number = 0
result = 0
for each_number in range(10):
    numbers = int(input("ENter any Number: "))
    sum_of_all_number += number

result = sum_of_all_number / 10
print(f'The average is {result}')
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but the input comes in loops  and if we break , the average is not correct!        reason- I'm doing this to find the average of any 10 numbers!